# Scope of PDO variables

Tags: function, pdo, scope

This might be fairly simple but I don't know how. Now, I'm using PDO to access MySQL. I create a connection to the db at the top of the script e.g. 
`$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=xyz",'usnm','pswd')`
Now when I call a function, it says that the variable `$db` is undefined. I have put the function in an external script which I have `required` at the top of the script.
Now my question is, what is the scope of PDO variables? Does it extend to functions called inside the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't to do with the scope of "PDO variables", it's just variables in general. In PHP, you can't access any variable throughout the whole application without a little bit of extra work. Refer to the [variable scope documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You can inject the database variable like:

```
function something($db){
}
```

and then pass the database variable into the function, or you could do:

```
function something(){
  global $db;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks . It has worked.I have opted for the 2nd approach. As a reward, I declare you FREE!

Comment: @GThuo Cheers. I'll go outside and play.

Comment: But before you go, I was starting to like the 3rd one, but it's bringing this Warning:  `Constants may only evaluate to scalar values in...`. Now what's up here?

Comment: @GThuo whoops. no you can't do the third method.

Comment: ok prisoner. I already implemented the 2nd one on all my functions and all is well.